# Align vertices behind each other

Tags: scripting, objects, vertices

Have seven objects behind each other in a straight row and aligned with x,y axis.

Zooming in, the vertex's from each object does not align to each other. Here and there they do, most are scattered. Is there a script or method to align these vertices as well?

Currently I have to click and drag each one to align up.
[image: vertex]

Comment: Assuming you just want the vertices aligned rather than the whole of each object, Box-select them all and then use S-X-0 to align them all on the X axis. Then you may have to move them all at once with G-X to place them exactly where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the vertices to 0: <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>  on the y and z axis, then merge them together.